# How to check if values zod schema sum up to a certain value

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have the following zod schema and I also want to check if the values sum up to 1:

```
const schema = z.object({
  value1: z.number(),
  value2: z.number(),
  value3: z.number(),
});
```

I want to apply the constraint that the values should sum up to 1. I was thinking of trying transform then checking if the resulting value is 1, but I am not sure if this will work and how I can check the transformed value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **transform** with **refine** to check for the values sum upto 1 or not...!

Try It like this...

```
const schema = z.object({
  value1: z.number(),
  value2: z.number(),
  value3: z.number(),
}).refine(obj => obj.value1 + obj.value2 + obj.value3 === 1, {
  message: "The sum of value1, value2, and value3 should be 1",
}).transform(obj => {
  const sum = obj.value1 + obj.value2 + obj.value3;
  return {
    ...obj,
    sum,
  };
});
```

Hope This Helps.....